# Receipts in dashboard and annual receipts

Tags: receipts

I'm running CiviCRM under Wordpress.

I'd like to give donators access to their receipts at any time. Do you know if I can add them in a sort of user dashboard, so they can download them as pdf (same pdf recieved by email) ?

Is there a way to generate annual receipts, with all year contributions ?

Thank you if someone has an idea !

Answer (score 4):

Do these users have their own individual logins to your website?  If not, it would be difficult to provide them access to their receipts again.  If they do, then some custom code could be written to generate them.

Your annual receipts is a bit more doable.  You could schedule an email to be sent to all donors on January 1, that listed their donations, or at least the total amount of donations. There is a CiviCRM extension called Summary Fields what keeps running balances which probably would help here.

(Note that listing the donations in the year might require a small amount of customization.)

Comment: Thank you. Receipt is generated once to be attached to email and then not saved at all ? So it should be dynamically generated again if we want to access it later ?
If you have an idea how to customize the user dashboard...
Thanks again

Comment: @EtienneLacroix Have you find a solution? This is a feature that interests me too. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @masetto. Did not remember very well butI think I did not get a good solution, sorry.